# Kivy application unexpectedly halting when using Threads

Tags: python, xcode, multithreading, kivy

I am not sure whether this is an iOS issue or whether this is an issue with Kivy or even with Python (e.g. https://bugs.python.org/issue37788), but I am experiencing some problems with threading.

I have built an iPad app using the Kivy framework that makes several calls to an API, and uses the threading module to asynchronously make requests. Below is the code that handles the API requests:

```
import json
import requests
import base64
import threading

def thread(function):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.start()
        return t
    return wrap


class MathPixAPI:

    stroke_url = '*******************'
    header = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "app_id": "*******************",
        "app_key": "*******************"
    }

    @thread
    def post_data(self, file_name: str, root):
        """
        Posts a base64 encoded image to the MathPixAPI then updates the data DictProperty of the ExpressionWriter that
        calls this function
        :param file_name: The name of the file - e.g. "image.png"
        :param root: The ExpressionWriter that calls the function
        """
        image_uri = "data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(open(file_name, "rb").read()).decode()
        r = requests.post("https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text",
                          data=json.dumps({'src': image_uri}),
                          headers=self.header)
        root.data = json.loads(r.text)
```

The app makes no more than 5 asynchronous requests at one time, and is called from the function below:

```
    def get_image_data(self):
        """
        The function first saves the ExpressionWriter.canvas as a PNG file to the user_data_directory (automatically
        determined depending on the device the user is running the app on). Then this images is sent to the MathPix API
        which then return data on the handwritten answer (see api.py for more details). The api call updates self.data
        which in turn calls self._on_data().
        """
        file_name = f'{App.get_running_app().user_data_dir}/image_{self.number}.png'
        self.export_to_png(file_name)
        MathPixAPI().post_data(file_name, self)
```

**This works really well**, up until the 20th-25th request, upon which the program halts. In Xcode I receive the following error log:

```
021-04-09 18:11:02.300179+0100 ccc-writer-3[4261:4790641] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior. trace=(
    0   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187cbb538 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 17859896
    1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ce56c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ce71f8 _dispatch_once_callout + 136
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187cbb4bc 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 17859772
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187cbb628 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 17860136
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187abbd64 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 15764836
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187aae150 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 15708496
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001877b2f20 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 12582688
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187cb2b30 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 17824560
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000187aacd50 8518EAE3-832B-3FF0-9FA5-9DBE3041F26C + 15703376
    10  ccc-writer-3                        0x0000000100822960 -[SDL_uikitviewcontroller showKeyboard] + 108
    11  ccc-writer-3                        0x0000000100823164 UIKit_ShowScreenKeyboard + 60
    12  ccc-writer-3                        0x00000001007ec490 SDL_StartTextInput + 92

... [A whole bunch of memory addresses] ...

    74  ccc-writer-3                        0x0000000100610df4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5432
    75  ccc-writer-3                        0x000000010054dfe0 function_code_fastcall + 120
    76  ccc-writer-3                        0x00000001005505f8 method_vectorcall + 264
    77  ccc-writer-3                        0x000000010054d95c PyVectorcall_Call + 104
    78  ccc-writer-3                        0x0000000100770c40 t_bootstrap + 80
    79  ccc-writer-3                        0x000000010065e8e8 pythread_wrapper + 28
    80  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cfbb3cb0 _pthread_start + 320
    81  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cfbbc778 thread_start + 8
)
2021-04-09 18:11:02.308745+0100 ccc-writer-3[4261:4790641] *** Assertion failure in -[_UISimpleFenceProvider trackSystemAnimationFence:], _UISimpleFenceProvider.m:51
2021-04-09 18:11:02.311976+0100 ccc-writer-3[4261:4790641] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'main thread only'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184dc686c 0x199de1c50 0x184ccc000 0x18606091c 0x186cd20bc 0x187777d30 0x1877cb888 0x186c00e58 0x1875b2610 0x1871c71b8 0x1871c54d0 0x1871c51f0 0x1871c674c 0x1871c67c8 0x1871c682c 0x187541c94 0x1871c3478 0x1871c2b88 0x1877b7f58 0x1877b2fc8 0x187cb2b30 0x187aacd50 0x100822960 0x100823164 0x1007ec490 0x1008d30b8 0x10055680c 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x100615e98 0x10054e160 0x10055058c 0x100614e6c 0x100611d50 0x10054dfe0 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x10054dfe0 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x100615e98 0x10054e160 0x100550664 0x10054d95c 0x100612888 0x100615e98 0x10060f87c 0x100859f50 0x10085e5dc 0x10085f020 0x100bc7598 0x100bc5c78 0x100beac94 0x100591568 0x1005908dc 0x100c116a0 0x1005908dc 0x100610d94 0x10054dfe0 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x100615e98 0x10054e160 0x10055058c 0x100614e6c 0x100611d50 0x100615e98 0x10060f87c 0x100859f50 0x10085e5dc 0x10085f020 0x100bc7598 0x100bc5c78 0x100bcbdc8 0x100beac94 0x100591568 0x1005908dc 0x100610d94 0x10054dfe0 0x10054d95c 0x100612888 0x10054dfe0 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x10054dfe0 0x100614e6c 0x100610df4 0x10054dfe0 0x1005505f8 0x10054d95c 0x100770c40 0x10065e8e8 0x1cfbb3cb0 0x1cfbbc778)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'main thread only'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am not sure what "*main thread only*" means nor do I have any idea how to resolve this issue. Can anyone clarify what this means and explain what the problem is? How can I stop my program from halting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue in Xcode by amending the runtime API checking.

Navigate to:

`Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run / Debug > Diagnostics`

then deselect `Main Thread Checker`